# how to access a BTLE attribute table from yocto linux

Tags: intel-edison, btle, bluetooth-gatt

I'm working on interfacing a BTLE peripheral with intel edison. I'm using puTTY for accessing linux environment. So far I have achieved the connection but when I list the attributes, it gives me services and characters with handle values. but I don't have any table to match the handle with respective services. I do have the complete BT protocol of the device so I know the UUID for each service but I don't know which handle is representing which service due to which I cannot configure the registers and read required data. How can I get an attribute table?

What I'm getting on the console is below:

[image]

[image]

and what I want is something like this sensorTag attribute table:
http://processors.wiki.ti.com/images/a/a8/BLE_SensorTag_GATT_Server.pdf

Comment: Could you add your "source" as text and desired output as image that is directly visible in your question - ideally cotnaining same data as input - so that each piece of data can be identified in both source and target?

Comment: Thankyou for prompt replying. I've worked out how to solve this issue but now the issue is that i cant access gatttool on my system. 
I'm running a bluez-5.37 on intel edison. i can access the hcitool and other listed tools but cant find gatttool. its not present in the /usr/bin directory and i dont know how to solve the issue.

Comment: There is no more `gattool` in BlueZ 5.xx. You have to use replacement IIUC.